# how to make g703 hero connect to old logitech gaming software? not G hub

Tags: logitech, logitech-gaming-software

how to make g703 hero connect to old logitech gaming software?
G hub is useless, the weakness of functions.

Answer (score 0):

What function do you need on lgs ? I think G-Hub have all function that LGS have.